ASP.NET Core project.dll can't find appsettings.Production.json file
I'm trying to deploy my ASP.NET Core project on ubuntu. I've copied the release files on my vm, installed the runtime and created a service file. However when I start the program I get the error

Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'appsettings.Production.json' was not found and is not optional. The expected physical path was '/appsettings.Production.json'.

Running dotnet publish --configuration Release outputs a Release folder which contains a net8.0 folder with all the project's files in it.
net8.0's contents
ubuntu@server-1:~$ ls Release/net8.0
API.deps.json                                      Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll
API.dll                                            Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll
API.exe                                            Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll
API.pdb                                            Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.dll
API.runtimeconfig.json                             Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll
Asp.Versioning.Abstractions.dll                    Microsoft.OpenApi.dll
Asp.Versioning.Http.dll                            MySqlConnector.dll
Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer.dll                 Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Asp.Versioning.Mvc.dll                             Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.dll
Castle.Core.dll                                    Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations.dll
ClassLibrary.dll                                   Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll
ClassLibrary.pdb                                   Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll
Discord.Net.Core.dll                               Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll
Discord.Net.Rest.dll                               System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.dll  System.Interactive.Async.dll
Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll                  System.Linq.Async.dll
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions.dll     appsettings.Development.json
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies.dll          appsettings.Production.json
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll       appsettings.json
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll                  publish
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions.dll

As you can see the appsettings.Production.json file is there but it's still not getting loaded.
This is my service file
[Unit]
Description=ASP.NET Core Website
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/ubuntu/Release/net8.0/API.dll
Restart-on=failure
User=ubuntu
Type=simple
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

In Program.cs I have
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.Production.json", false);

It works locally on my PC but not on the ubuntu vm. What am I doing wrong?
I'm not changing any other configuration, the ContentRootPath is the default one (/).
Unless the ContentRootPath being / points to ubuntu's / directory I'm confused why this is happening.

Are you setting the working directory to the folder that contains the json file?

Setting the working directory through the service file? Otherwise as I said I'm leaving everything to default.

I solved it by setting WorkingDirectory to the net8.0 directory in the Service section of the service file.
